# How to avoid memory leaks in callback?

Tags: java, memory-management, callback, weak-references

Effective Java says:

> A third common source of memory leaks
>   is listeners and other callbacks. If
>   you implement an API where clients
>   register callbacks but don’t
>   deregister them explicitly, they will
>   accumulate unless you take some
>   action. The best way to ensure that
>   callbacks are garbage collected
>   promptly is to store only weak
>   references to them, for instance, by
>   storing them only as keys in a
>   WeakHashMap.

I am a beginner in Java. Could somebody teach me how to create weak references in callbacks and tell me how they solve the memory leak problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/88888889-java-util/1475-using-weakhashmap-for-listener-lists.html) article

The key take aways are :

> You can think of direct references as
>   strong references that require no
>   extra coding to create or access the
>   object. The remaining three types of
>   references are subclasses of the
>   Reference class found in the
>   java.lang.ref package. Soft references
>   are provided by the SoftReference
>   class, weak references by the
>   WeakReference class, and phantom
>   references by PhantomReference.
>
> Soft references act like a data cache.
>   When system memory is low, the garbage
>   collector can arbitrarily free an
>   object whose only reference is a soft
>   reference. In other words, if there
>   are no strong references to an object,
>   that object is a candidate for
>   release. The garbage collector is
>   required to release any soft
>   references before throwing an
>   OutOfMemoryException.
>
> Weak references are weaker than soft
>   references. If the only references to
>   an object are weak references, the
>   garbage collector can reclaim the
>   memory used by an object at any time.
>   There is no requirement for a low
>   memory situation. Typically, memory
>   used by the object is reclaimed in the
>   next pass of the garbage collector.
>
> Phantom references relate to cleanup
>   tasks. They offer a notification
>   immediately before the garbage
>   collector performs the finalization
>   process and frees an object. Consider
>   it a way to do cleanup tasks within an
>   object.

followed by the WeakListModel listing which I won't post to avoid cluttering this response.

Comment: I would just like to note that the link is broken

Answer (score 10):

To illustrate the concept with a quick (crude) example, consider the following:

```
public interface ChangeHandler {
    public void handleChange();
}

public class FileMonitor {

    private File file;
    private Set<ChangeHandler> handlers = new HashSet<ChangeHandler>();

    public FileMonitor(File file) { 
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void registerChangeHandler(ChangeHandler handler) {
        this.handlers.add(handler);
    } 

    public void unregisterChangeHandler(ChangeHandler handler) {
        this.handlers.remove(handler);
    }

    ...
}
```

If a client class then uses this `FileMonitor` API, they might do this:

```
public class MyClass {

    File myFile = new File(...);
    FileMonitor monitor = new FileMonitor(myFile);

    public void something() {
        ...
        ChangeHandler myHandler = getChangeHandler();
        monitor.registerChangeHandler(myHandler);
        ...
    }
}
```

If the author of the `MyClass` then forgets to call `unregisterChangeHandler()` when it's done with the handler, the `FileMonitor`'s `HashSet` will forever reference the instance that was registered, causing it to remain in memory until the `FileMonitor` is destroyed or the application quits.

To prevent this, Bloch is suggesting using a weak-referencing collection instead of the `HashSet`, so that if your instance of `MyClass` is destroyed, the reference will be removed from the monitor's collection.

You might replace the `HashSet` in `FileMonitor` with a [`WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) and use the handlers as the keys, since the latter will automatically remove the handler from the collection when all other references to the object are gone.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I still don't quite understand. When something() returns, the strong reference myHandler will go out of scope. Is it not so that the handler referenced by the WeakHashMap can then be destroyed at any time (even if the MyClass instance remains)? That's not what you want right?

Comment: Ah, I'm starting to see ... You could use WeakHashMap<MyClass, ChangeHandler>, then the key is in fact the instance of MyClass.

Comment: I think myHandler  should go after something() returns, even if the MyClass instance remains. so WeakHashMap<ChangeHandler ,?> is better than WeakHashMap<MyClass, ChangeHandler>

Answer (score 2):

Here you may find a clear and **practical** **explanation** as well:
[Memory leaks in Android — identify, treat and avoid](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8#.4g8q3m83y)