# Avoid memory leaks in callbacks?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid memory leaks in callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859464/how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-callback)

Effective Java says:

> A third common source of memory leaks is listeners and other
>   callbacks. If you implement an API where clients register callbacks
>   but don’t deregister them explicitly, they will accumulate unless you
>   take some action. The best way to ensure that callbacks are garbage
>   collected promptly is to store only weak references to them, for
>   instance, by storing them only as keys in a WeakHashMap.

I am unable to understand this. could someone explain this ?

Comment: This question is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859464/how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-callback

Answer (score 3):

If you add call backs to a collection, but don't remove them, this will lead to a memory leak.  One way to handle this (apart from making sure such objects are always removed correctly) is to store the listeners in a weak collection.  A weak collection can remove entries when that element/listener no longer has a strong reference.

The problem with this approach is you cannot have a listener which is only referenced in the collection as it will disappear randomly (on the next GC)

I tend to use listeners which are not referenced anywhere else and try to ensure unused listeners are removed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Holding a weak reference to an object does not prevent it from becoming garbage collected - if there are no more strong references to the object, eventually it will be garbage collected and you will no longer be able to access it via the `WeakReference` you have stored. Google `Java weak references tutorial` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It means: If a listener or callback references to the object itself, then the referenced object will never be GCed since the listener or callback is still there and there is a reference to the object from this, causing a memory leak.